# Unable to Start IRB via Terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

I installed Ruby + Rails using the instructions provided by http://installrails.com/. I'm trying to launch IRB in the Terminal, and I get the following error output:

```
FishHeads:jhu katie$ irb
/Users/katie/.irbrc:1: warning: encountered \r in middle of line, treated as a mere space
/Users/katie/.rvm/scripts/irbrc.rb:70:in `load': /Users/katie/.irbrc:1:syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError)
IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT_MODE] = false
                                ^
    from /Users/katie/.rvm/scripts/irbrc.rb:70:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/katie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/katie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/katie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/.irbrc:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/katie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/init.rb:236:in `load'
    from /Users/katie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/init.rb:236:in `run_config'
    from /Users/katie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb/init.rb:19:in `setup'
    from /Users/katie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/irb.rb:380:in `start'
    from /Users/katie/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Can someone please get me started on the path of how to fix this?

Comment: Type `ruby -v` and post what you get.

Comment: @JonahR

`ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]`

Comment: You have ruby installed which is good. Do you know what your `FishHeads:jhu` means?

Comment: Yes; FishHeads is my computer's name and jhu is the directory I was working in when I tried to launch IRB.

Comment: Do you have Windows or Mac?

Comment: I fixed it. I have to figure out the specifics, but my .irbrc file was problematic. I replaced the one I had with the one I found at http://drnicwilliams.com/2006/10/12/my-irbrc-for-consoleirb/, and I am now able to run irb. Thanks for your help!